# merging two pandas dataframes where new column is created

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two python dataframes: One df which contains information on sites where some survey has occured:

```
sites = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A1', 2, 3], ['B3', 5, 6], ['B5', 8, 9]]),
                 columns=['Site_ID', 'SomeVal1', 'SomeVal2'])
sites.set_index('Site_ID')
```

A second df with laboratory analyses for each site, where an individual site can have different analyses, related to depth of sampling (indicated by the field "Depth type"

```
LabData = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A1_a_s','A1', 'S', 300], ['A1_a_g','A1', 'G', 600], ['B3_b_s','B3', 'S', 900],['B3_b_s','B3', 'G', 90],['B5_b_g','B5', 'G', 390],['B5_b_s','B5', 'S', 550]]),
                   columns=['Chem_ID', 'Site_ID', 'Depth_type', 'Val'])


LabData.set_index('Chem_ID')
```

I would like to assign two columns to the sites df with the labdata for the two depth types (which are coded consistently) to generate a result that looks like:

```
Site_With_data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A1', 2, 3,300,600], ['B3', 5, 6,900,90], ['B5', 8, 9,550,550]]),
                     columns=['Site_ID', 'SomeVal1', 'SomeVal2','Val_depth_type=S','Val_depth_type=G'])
```

I tried different ways of df.merge but I don't get the right merge type. Appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) for reshape and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to `sites DataFrame`:

```
df1 = LabData.pivot('Site_ID', 'Depth_type','Val').add_prefix('Val_depth_type=')
df = sites.join(df1, on='Site_ID').reset_index()
print (df)
  Site_ID SomeVal1 SomeVal2 Val_depth_type=G Val_depth_type=S
0      A1        2        3              600              300
1      B3        5        6               90              900
2      B5        8        9              390              550
```

EDIT: If duplicates, use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggregate function:

```
df1 = LabData.pivot_table(index='Site_ID', 
                          columns='Depth_type',
                          values='Val',
                          aggfunc='mean').add_prefix('Val_depth_type=')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it's not working for me because of the duplication in index:
    ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: That didn't work either, because the duplicates are in the Site_ID field. Which is not numeric. It raises the error:
'DataError: No numeric types to aggregate'

Comment: @user9118870 - data are not numeric? `df['val'] = df['val'].astype(int)` or `df['val'] = pd.to_numeric(df['val'], errors='coerce')` working before `pivot_table` ?